# javascript getting failed after the ajax request is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch data from local network IP. It works fine if I am in the local network. It fails when accessed from outside, which is understandable. But the jquery error block is not getting executed, it just breaks the code and the page is stuck forever. Here is the code:

```
 var url = "http://10.0.0.1:8080/status";
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        data :  {},
        success: function(response){
            var clientState = response.clientState;
            $(".clientstate-input").val(clientState);
            document.loginform.submit();
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.error(response);
            $(".clientstate-input").val("0");
            document.loginform.submit();
        }
});
```

Error:

[image: Console Message]

[image: Network Tab]

Comment: are you accessing it from "outside" (*wherever that is*) using the same IP address? i.e. `10.0.0.1`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes. I understand it should not work, but atleast error block should get executed.

Comment: ahh, ok, so, what does happen in the browser developer tools network and/or console?

Comment: @JaromandaX updated the post

Comment: Is that CORS issue? Are you able to see any CORS error on the console?

Comment: No sign of CORS. One single error in console, which is present in console.

Comment: @JaromandaX I found the solution the issue is I am using older version of jQuery,the same code works fine with new version.Thanks for the help though!!

Comment: can't be CORS if there isn't a server :p - I think the problem is because it's JSONP - but surely when the script tag load fails, jquery can handle that a bit better? Or maybe not, maybe jquery just fails poorly (looks like it did, but now it handles this correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to use a Promise:

```
var url = "http://10.0.0.1:8080/status";
 $.ajax({
     url: url,
     dataType:"jsonp",
     crossDomain: true,
     data :  {}
})
.then(response => {
    var clientState = response.clientState;
    $(".clientstate-input").val(clientState);
    document.loginform.submit();
})
.catch(response => {
    console.error(response);
    $(".clientstate-input").val("0");
    document.loginform.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of using older version of jQuery. Updated the library and everything was working fine.